Cypress - Make assertions before letting the interception return the fixture
Situation
I am working on a page which has a form. When the button in the form is clicked, a request is sent to the backend and the page changes to show that it's performing the operation (a progress bar appears, the background color changes, the button is disabled).
When the response arrives, the changes on the page are reverted and some fields are updated.
Now, I want to write a Cypress test that intercepts the call to the backend, checks that the button is disabled and all, then respond with a fixture before asserting that the fields have been updated. I know that I may set the delay field in the StaticResponse object of cy.intercept, but I am wondering if there is a way to do this that does not involve waiting for an arbitrary amount of time.
What I would want
I would like to be able to write something akin to this:
describe('Pseudocode', () => {
  it('could be nice', () => {
    cy.intercept('GET', '/printers', ['printer1']);
  
    // The 'wait' field would instruct intercept to wait for `cy.wait()` before returning
    const hypotheticalStaticResponse = { fixture: 'print-response-ok.json', wait: true };
    cy.intercept('POST', '/print', hypotheticalStaticResponse).as('printRequest');
  
    cy.visit('/form');
  
    cy.get('mat-form-field#box-identifier input').as('boxIdentifier');
    cy.get('div#print > button').as('printButton');
  
    cy.get('@boxIdentifier').type('1234567');
    // The call is made when the button is clicked
    cy.get('@printButton').click();
  
    cy.get('app-shipping-label').should('have.class', 'printing');
    cy.get('@printButton').should('be.disabled');
    cy.get('mat-progress-bar').should('be.visible');
  
    // The request would be answered only once we hit this instruction
    cy.wait('@printRequest');
  
    cy.get('app-shipping-label').should('have.class', 'ready');
    cy.get('mat-progress-bar').should('not.exist');
  });
}

What I tried
describe('Assertions on my form', () => {
  it("doesn't work without delay", () => {
    cy.intercept('GET', '/printers', ['printer1']);
  
    cy.intercept('POST', '/print', { fixture: 'print-response-ok.json' }).as('printRequest');
  
    cy.visit('/form');
  
    cy.get('div#print > button').as('printButton');
  
    cy.get('mat-form-field#box-identifier input').type('1234567');
    // The call is made when the button is clicked
    cy.get('@printButton').click();
  
    // Fails, because the fixture was already returned
    cy.get('app-shipping-label').should('have.class', 'printing');
    cy.get('@printButton').should('be.disabled');
    cy.get('mat-progress-bar').should('be.visible');
  
    cy.wait('@printRequest');
  
    cy.get('app-shipping-label').should('have.class', 'ready');
    cy.get('mat-progress-bar').should('not.exist');
  });
  
  it("doesn't work with inner gets", () => {
    cy.intercept('GET', '/printers', ['printer1']);
  
    cy.intercept('POST', '/print', { fixture: 'print-response-ok.json', delay: 500 }).as('printRequest');
  
    cy.visit('/form');
  
    cy.get('div#print > button').as('printButton');
  
    cy.get('mat-form-field#box-identifier input').type('1234567');
    // The call is made when the button is clicked
    cy.get('@printButton').click();
  
    cy.get('app-shipping-label').should('have.class', 'printing');
    cy.get('@printButton').should('be.disabled');
    cy.get('mat-progress-bar').should('be.visible');
  
    cy.wait('@printRequest').then(() => {
      // CypressError: `cy.then()` failed because you are mixing up async and sync code.
      cy.get('app-shipping-label').should('have.class', 'printing');
      cy.get('@printButton').should('be.disabled');
      cy.get('mat-progress-bar').should('be.visible');
    });
  
    cy.get('app-shipping-label').should('have.class', 'ready');
    cy.get('mat-progress-bar').should('not.exist');
  });
  
  it('works with a delay, but is there another way?', () => {
    cy.intercept('GET', '/printers', ['printer1']);
  
    cy.intercept('POST', '/print', { fixture: 'print-response-ok.json', delay: 500 }).as('printRequest');
  
    cy.visit('/form');
  
    cy.get('div#print > button').as('printButton');
  
    cy.get('mat-form-field#box-identifier input').type('1234567');
    // The call is made when the button is clicked
    cy.get('@printButton').click();
  
    cy.get('app-shipping-label').should('have.class', 'printing');
    cy.get('@printButton').should('be.disabled');
    cy.get('mat-progress-bar').should('be.visible');
  
    cy.wait('@printRequest');
  
    cy.get('app-shipping-label').should('have.class', 'ready');
    cy.get('mat-progress-bar').should('not.exist');
  });
};


One workaround solution I found was to split it into two tests; the second one has no delay in the interception and checks what happens after the response comes, while the first one "blocks" the request with (req) => {} as a dynamic interceptor, which allows me to test what happens between the call and the response. But it feels "hacky".

Is it not better to just add a delay rather than to block it altogether?

BTW there is a method for blocking: req.destroy().

If you add a delay to the intercept response (see Controlling the response) your test should work as-is.
This page simulates the behaviours you describe:
<body>
  <form>
    <div>
      <app-shipping-label>Waiting to print</app-shipping-label>
    </div>
    <mat-progress-bar hidden>Progress...</mat-progress-bar>
    <div id="print">
      <button>Print</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <script>
    const button = document.querySelector('button')    
    button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {

      button.setAttribute("disabled", "")

      const shippingLabel = document.querySelector('app-shipping-label')
      shippingLabel.classList.add('printing')
      shippingLabel.innerText = 'Printing the label'

      const progressBar = document.querySelector('mat-progress-bar')
      progressBar.removeAttribute('hidden')

      fetch('/print', { 
        method: "POST",
        body: "something"
      }).then(response => {
        shippingLabel.classList.add('ready')
        progressBar.setAttribute('hidden', '')
      })
    })
  </script>
</body>

This is the test
cy.fixture('example.json').then(fixtureData => {
  cy.intercept('POST', '/print', (req) => {
    req.reply({
      statusCode: 201,
      body: fixtureData,
      delay: 1000, // milliseconds
    })
  }).as('printRequest')
})

cy.visit('/')

cy.get('div#print > button').as('printButton')
cy.get('@printButton').click()

cy.get('app-shipping-label').should('have.class', 'printing');
cy.get('@printButton').should('be.disabled');
cy.get('mat-progress-bar').should('be.visible');

cy.wait('@printRequest')          // added check to verify fixture stubbing
  .then(interception => {
    expect(interception.response.body.email).to.eq('hello@cypress.io')
  })

cy.get('app-shipping-label').should('have.class', 'ready');
cy.get('mat-progress-bar').should('not.be.visible');

The test passes, this is the log


Thanks for your thorough answer! However, that's what I'd hoped to avoid: using an arbitrary duration to wait, instead of programmatically signaling that the fixture may be returned.

Looks like you're not understanding - Cypress provides the delay option to allow the test long enough to make assertions before the response appears. It's the same concept as using cy.clock() and cy.tick() to control the timing in the app.

The difference I see with cy.clock() and cy.tick() is that you don't control exactly when the request resolves, whereas the clock won't tick until you call cy.tick(), which can happen whenever you want.

Say you set a delay of 20 ms, and it so happens that the response comes between two assertions that were assuming the request has not come back yet. The test would fail. Increasing the value is possible, but it's still arbitrary, and it makes the test take longer than necessary, because it might take 21ms to make the assertions one time, while taking 13ms another time.

500ms to 1000ms delay is acceptable when you are providing a fixture response, there is not network call to slow the response, only the response time of the app.
